# Mouse.click() doesnt pass exact x,y position location to click action

Tags: karate

Im working on an angular js ui project which incorporates dynamic graphs at runtime. Aspects of the svg elements result in inprecise location positions (see screen shot below of text labels in the piechart legend. The values on the x axis in the first div column are precise, but in the 2nd and third columns they are not "exact" / "precise" (see Contract Pending, Contract Accepted, Sales Record Pending, and SalesRecord Rejected)

[image]

When I performed a mouse("[svg rel path here").click() (in test runtime) returns a screen position location of x with decimals values (see example below "x:251.875" this gets transformed/stripped in the next action (performing click action / see below) to "x:251" which performs the click on nothing (as the label is not found at that location). So even though the result is a 200 / "Pass" - the item has not been selected.

[image]

In the mean time, I have worked around by finding the position and rounding up to the nearest whole number - in the example I mentioned - I have rounded 251.875 to 252. This has allowed me to click each of these "in-precise" x-axis text labels. I then perform a * mouse().move(252, 494).click() step which works as the expected click action should.

Sorry I cant provide project to reproduce - I hope the summary provides enough detail.

Regards,

JB18

Comment: can you PLEASE confirm if this is fixed in the upcoming version ? https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: After upgrading POM with karate.core 0.9.9.RC3 and rerunning - this is not an issue in this point release and therefore is not a bug  NO ACTION REQUIRED.
Thanks @PeterThomas